# Style of Danza Del Viejo Boyero by Alberto Ginastera

Tags: history, styles, interpretation

I have struggled with understanding the style of this song, and I guess it is open to interpretation, but I was wondering whether to play it like an "old shepherd" as its name suggests, or a racing fast song like the [third dance in the same Op. 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danzas_Argentinas#Danza_del_gaucho_matrero,_Op._2_no._3) (*Danza del gaucho matrero*)?

Does anyone know anything about the history or events surrounding the music (or its meaning) that can help me understand how it's supposed to be played?

Comment: By "third movement" do you mean [*Danza del gaucho matero*, Op. 2 No. 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danzas_Argentinas#Danza_del_gaucho_matrero,_Op._2_no._3) (sample performance by Martha Argerich [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8U2CrKkFvww))?  Here's the [score for *Danza del viejo boyero*, Op. 2 No. 1](https://musescore.com/bladesofgrass/ginastera-danzas-argentinas-no-1-danza-del-viejo-boyero) and [Martha Argerich's performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XivxrrsHq-0) or a live performance [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30YTxiszy0c) which is similar but a little slower.

Comment: I'd expect all 3 movements to contrast with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the input...yes I meant danza del gaucho matrero